# Java or pseudocode for creating text combination

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I am trying to break a string into combinations as following:

```
If input = ab
Result of all combinations:
ab
a b

If input = abc
Result of all combinations:
abc 
a bc
ab c
a b c

If input = abcd
Reslut of all combinations:
abcd
a bc d
a bcd
a b cd
a b c d
ab cd
ab c d
abc d

If input = abcde
Reslut of alla combinations:
abcde
a bcde
a b cde
a b c de
a b cd e
a b c d e
a bc de
a bc d e
a bcd e
ab cde
ab cd e
ab c de
ab c d e
abc de
abc d e
abcd e
```

This will be very hard manually if the string is as long as abcdefghijklm. Do you have any idea how I can do this programmatically?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: Yes it does. Combinations should always be in the same order as the input string.

Comment: I meant, does it matter whether I print a bcd before ab cd or not?

Comment: Looks to me like you want to generate a power set i. e. the set of all sets. Here is a [blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-power-set-of-a-set) for an algorithm to get the power set. In order to print `a` before `b` as that information will be lost when using a set you could use Map to map the positions.

Comment: @AdityaRastogi, it should always be in the right order as abcd, a bcd, a b cd, a bc d and so on. The letter 'a' will always be the first letter, and 'b' the second letter and so on.

Comment: (1) `ab` has `a b`. (2) `abcd` has `a b c d`. (3) `abcde` has `a b c d e`. (4) Why does `abc` NOT have `a b c`? Is this an editing error, or is there some other algorithm/logic going on here?

Comment: @Mushroomator, I don't think I can use sets. As you mentioned I will loose the order by using sets. It has to be in order 'a' as a first letter, 'b' as second and so on.

Comment: @Madeline I guess your expected output is wrong.

Comment: @Madeline [this algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/) to generate the power set should work (and it's surprisingly simple). It will preserve the order of the characters.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, it is recursive relations in combinatorics. You want for example create a list of combination from input=abcd, a list as following:
abcd
a;bc;d
a;bcd
a;b;cd
a;b;c;d
ab;cd
ab;c;d
abc;d
space, semicolon or komma doesn't matter 
total 8 combinatoins because =−1+...+1+1 which make 2^(n-1). In this case n is 4.

Comment: Okay. You didn't answer the question. Should `abc` then produce `a b c`? It doesn't in your expected output, so we can't jump to the conclusion that this is a "recursive relations in combinatorics".

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I just found an error in my first text listing combintions. I changed it. Yes, abc should produce a b c.

Comment: If the order matters, then you need to eliminate the inconsistencies in the output, like `a bc d` is followed by the `a bcd`; `ab cd e` goes before the `ab c de` and `ab c d e`. Seems like their order need to be the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

The binary counting approach from the link will work, but instead you'll use the 1s and 0s to determine if a space should be present or not between letters.

We count in decimal from zero up to `2^(numLetters - 1) - 1`. When we convert the decimal number to binary, we left pad using zeroes for a total length of `numLetters - 1`.

For example, here's the "correct order" that I'd expect to get the combinations in for `abcde`:

[image]

Would generating the combinations in this order be acceptable? If so, I'll post some example code to accomplish this.

Comment: Brilliant answer. The "Space between letters" trick is smart!

Comment: As for the order: I think it's easy to sort the resulted combination according to the OP's needs.

Comment: This looks like a great assignment to challenge my High School AP Computer Science students with... ;)

Comment: @Idle_Mind, your last solution was absolutely great. I am happy to assist you with many computer science problems for your students ;)

Comment: Were you able to write some working code from that?